# Rebase instead of merge in Xcode 9

Tags: git, github, git-merge, xcode9, git-rebase

I am trying to rebase my local repository from GitHub but there is no option in the Xcode when I am pulling. In other clients like SourceTree there is this option to be checked.

Is there any way to rebase instead of merge on pull?